# When using -replace in powershell to replace "../" with "ref/" the dots ("..") become a wildcard

Tags: powershell

so basically I have this script

```
$find = "../"
    $replace = "ref/"
    $content = Get-Content $($file.FullName) -Raw
    #write replaced content back to the file
    $content -replace $find,$replace | Out-File $($file.FullName)
```

It should replace hrefs like "../css/etc" to "ref/css/etc", which it does, but then it also changes everything that has 2 characters followed by a slash, like "google.com/anything" gets turned into google.cref/anything"

MS docs doesn't say anything about dots being wildcards: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-7

Any ideas? Cheers

Comment: `-replace` is a regex operator, and in regex `.` is a wildcard

Comment: Cheers for that, do you know any walkarounds for this? Will look further into it, thanks

Comment: Yes, either escape manually `\.` or have the `[regex]` class do it for you (see the duplicate question I linked)